# Multimodule tests which depends on each other

Tags: maven, maven-docker-plugin

I'm currently writing integration tests between 2 modules:

- Module A - contains a REST service which can be dockerized via maven plugin
- Module B - contains integration tests which depends on Module A docker to be up and running

So I used failsafe plugin which contains the pre-integration-tests phase and post-integration-tests.

In the pre-integration-tests I start the dockers and after all the integration tests of all the submodules have finished I want to kill those dockers.

In the docker plugin that I use (fabric8) there is also 2 phases which I use in the above phases which area docker:start and docker:stop

The problem appears when I run the entire project, the dockers are killed in Module A before Module B tests are running, so I thought that if I could tell the parent module which holds them something like :

- Start Module B docker:start plugin
- Run integration tests of all project
- Start Module B docker:stop plugin

It would really solve my problem, but is there a way to call phases of submodules from parent module or even revered, attach a submodule phase to the parent module phase from the submodule

Comment: The solution is to do the whole integration tests within a separate module which in your case is module B which contains all the configuration for that. Be are to define a dependency to Module A to guarantee having built module A before running integration tests...and may be you can use a profile to let run the integration tests only if you really like or in a CI environment like Jenkins. And finally there is no option/possibility to call phased from the parent etc.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Maven doesn't have the ability to pause a module's build until a condition in another module is met; Maven runs a sub-module's build fully before going to build another sub-module.

You can however, make `Module B` depend on `Module A` (even depend on a set of test classes from it), and thus you could start your REST Service, within the build of `Module B`, as part of your integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your setup, **building** `Module A` has nothing to do with starting/stopping containers; thus, `Module A` shouldn’t do it.

Instead, the container should be started and stopped in `Module B`’s `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phases, respectively. After all, `Module B`’s `integration-test` phase needs a running container, not `Module A`.

If you are not used to Maven’s (opinionated) way of doing things, this may seem unnecessarily restrictive, but Maven merely *forces* you to do the Right Thing. Think about it like this: If, in the future, another `Module C` also needs a running docker container, e.g., to run some *other* tests against, you wouldn’t want to recycle a single docker container (started by `Module A`). As this risks `Module B` and `Module C` interacting in funny ways, each module should get its own docker container to work against.

Comment: Each module has it's setup of docker, but what happens what you have Module A to need Module B to be up? You need to dockerize Module B but the setup is in it's pom.xml file..